# Nested MultiBinding(s)

Tags: c#, wpf, multibinding

I've been playing around with WPF for quite a while now, but for the first time today, I needed to nest a `MultiBinding` inside another, something like:

```
<MultiBinding>
   <Binding />       
   <MultiBinding>
      <Binding />
      <Binding />
   </MultiBinding>
</MultiBinding>
```

I get an exception indicating it's not allowed by the framework:

> XamlParseException was unhandled: Add value to collection of type 'System.Collections.ObjectModel.Collection(System.Windows.Data.BindingBase)' threw an exception.

The `InnerException` is more explicit:

> BindingCollection does not support items of type MultiBinding. Only Binding is allowed.

So digging the web for more info, I stumbled upon [this Microsoft Connect issue](http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/653138/nested-multibindings) which is exactly my problem.

> Thank you for the feedback. WPF doesn't support this today. This
>   feature has been requested for years (most recently earlier this month
>   - see https://connect.microsoft.com/WPF/feedback/details/650164/nested-multibinding).
>   We'll continue to consider this for future releases.

Right now I've made my peace that I won't have it easy. Still I need this, **how can I nest MultiBindings**?

Comment: What is it that you're trying to do, that you want to nest multibindings?

Comment: I am converting boolean values with complex orders of precedence and while some of them are already booleans, others need a conversion first and thus are themselves embedded in other `IMultiValueConverter`(s).

Comment: If your other MultiValueConverters have no more than two input values, you could use a converter with a parameter instead... or you could use a converter with a complex parameter to input multiple values, which is a little bit of work but should do the trick.  If that sounds feasible I could post a sample?

Comment: For argument's sake, let's say most of my converters only take 2 inputs. Parameter cannot be bound, it is not a dependency property :/

Comment: Now sure, I could go and leverage the Hillberg's Freezable trick, or DatacontextSpy and the likes, but if you ever used that, you know it's squishy...

Comment: There are ways of binding non-dependency properties, using some filthy attached properties - not quite as squishy as Hillberg's, as long as you can work within the limitations.  Not come across DatacontextSpy before...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

simply use one multibinding an a MultiConverter.

or what i prefer expose your condition in one property of your viewmodel/datacontext.

Comment: Yeah but that defeats the whole purpose of it, If I need to create a new converter that just combines other converters, and since i got around a hundred of them... That's a lot of boilerplate.

Comment: Indeed it would, but I'm trying to reuse what I already have ;)

Comment: can you expose your condition in one property of your viewmodel? so you wouldnt need a multiconverter/multibinding at all

Comment: I ended up doing something like that.

Answer (score 8):

I know that this is an old question but I think this this is a much nicer approach:

```xml
<FrameworkElement x:Name="IsBuyAndAmountInReference">
    <FrameworkElement.Tag>
        <MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource LogicAndToBool}">
            <Binding Path="OrderData.IsBuy" />
            <Binding Path="OrderData.AmountInReference" />
        </MultiBinding>
    </FrameworkElement.Tag>
</FrameworkElement>
<FrameworkElement x:Name="IsSellAndAmountInBase">
    <FrameworkElement.Tag>
        <MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource LogicAndToBool}">
            <Binding Path="OrderData.IsBuy" Converter="{StaticResource BooleanToBooleanInvert}" />
            <Binding Path="OrderData.AmountInReference" Converter="{StaticResource BooleanToBooleanInvert}" />
        </MultiBinding>
    </FrameworkElement.Tag>
</FrameworkElement>

<Slider Grid.Row="2" Grid.ColumnSpan="4">
    <Slider.Visibility>
        <MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource LogicOrToVisibility}">
            <Binding ElementName="IsBuyAndAmountInReference" Path="Tag" />
            <Binding ElementName="IsSellAndAmountInBase" Path="Tag" />
        </MultiBinding>
    </Slider.Visibility>
</Slider>
```

Answer (score 7):

An alternative to the other suggestions is to use attached properties to hold nested `MultiBinding`s as intermediate values.

For example, instead of:

```
<Element>
  <Element.Property>
    <MultiBinding>
      <Binding Path="A" />       
      <MultiBinding>
        <Binding Path="B" />
        <Binding Path="C" />
      </MultiBinding>
    </MultiBinding>
  </Element.Property>
</Element>
```

...do this:

```
<Element Name="ElementName">
  <ElementProperties.AttachedProperty>
    <MultiBinding>
      <Binding Path="B" />
      <Binding Path="C" />
    </MultiBinding>
  </ElementProperties.AttachedProperty>
  <Element.Property>
    <MultiBinding>
      <Binding Path="A" />       
      <Binding ElementName="ElementName" Path="(ElementProperties.AttachedProperty)" />
    </MultiBinding>
  </Element.Property>
</Element>
```

I know this question is more than six years old now, but I ran into it so someone else will, too.

Answer (score 5):

If you have a converter that takes a parameter, you can do something like this:

- Create a class for passing the "fixed" data to your converter
- Add `DependencyProperties` to the class (so that you can bind the values in Xaml)
- In your xaml, use a binding with a converter instead of a multibinding, something like this:

  ```
  <MultiBinding>
      <Binding Source="SomeObject" Path="CoreValue" Converter="{StaticResource YourNewConverter}">
          <Binding.ConverterParameter>
              <ns:ParameterClass Value1="{Binding Parameter1}" Value2="{Binding Parameter1}" />
          </Binding.ConverterParameter>
      </Binding>
   ....
  ```

The limitation is that (AFAIK) the value will only be recalculated if `CoreValue` changes - it won't automatically rebind if the converter parameters change.

(Apologies for any errors, I'm typing this without the benefit of VS to test in...)

Comment: I think it's a valid idea, but it would take too long to optimize with inheriting DataContext so that ParameterClass's properties can be bound to.

Answer (score 5):

I realise that this is an old question now, but I just hit exactly the same problem as the OP. Fortunately in my case I could bind to a sub-element where the result of the multi-binding was already being calculated, but it got me thinking...

A (though admittedly not very clean) solution would be to write the value of the multi-value binding into a 'spare' property such as an element's 'Tag' which you can then reference in your other multi-value bindings by specifying the 'ElementName' attribute.

If you need more than a single nested multi-value binding then you could create a 'fake' object with some dependency properties on it to store multiple intermediate results.

A pity that Microsoft don't implement a properly nested system...

Answer (score 0):

If you're binding to a string you can use StringFormat just like in this example:

```
 <TextBlock>
   <TextBlock.Text>
     <MultiBinding StringFormat="{}{0:0.###}/{1:0.###}" Mode="OneWay">
                        <Binding ElementName="This" Path="AggregatedDocDetail.ConfirmedQty"></Binding>
                        <Binding ElementName="This" Path="AggregatedDocDetail.Qty">   </Binding>
       </MultiBinding>
     </TextBlock.Text>
   </TextBlock>
```

Comment: I'm binding to booleans (see comments of the question) and also to POCOs.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a simple binding proxy as well.

```
<DataGrid.ContextMenu>
    <ContextMenu>
        ...
        <MenuItem Click="MenuItem_Click" Header="Use in filter" Command="{Binding SetCatFilterCommand}">
            <MenuItem.Resources>
                <local:BindingProxy x:Key="AsLitterIsEnabled" >
                    <local:BindingProxy.Data>
                        <MultiBinding Converter="{local:ViewCatConverter}"  
                            ConverterParameter="AsLitterIsEnabled">
                            <Binding Path="Heart.Cat" Mode="OneWay"/>
                            <Binding Path="Heart.SelectedLitters"                                 Mode="OneWay"/>
                        </MultiBinding>
                    </local:BindingProxy.Data>
                </local:BindingProxy>
            </MenuItem.Resources>
            <MenuItem.CommandParameter>
                <MultiBinding Converter="{local:MultiValueToArrayConverter}">
                    <Binding Path="Heart.SelectedLitters"/>
                    <Binding Source="AsLitter"/>
                    <Binding Path="CatFilter"/>
                    <Binding Path="Data" Source="{StaticResource AsLitterIsEnabled}"/>
                </MultiBinding>
             </MenuItem.CommandParameter>
         </MenuItem>
         ...
    </ContextMenu>
</DataGrid.ContextMenu>
```

The BindingProxy class:

```
using System.Windows;

public class BindingProxy : Freezable
{
    public static readonly DependencyProperty DataProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("Data", typeof(object),
        typeof(BindingProxy));

    public object Data
    {
        get => GetValue(DataProperty);
        set => SetValue(DataProperty, value);
    }

    protected override Freezable CreateInstanceCore()
    {
        return new BindingProxy();
    }
}
```